# Translation of “autotelic“

Tags: traduction

> A thing which is **autotelic** is described as "having a purpose in and not apart from itself".
>
> Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi describes people who are **internally driven**, and who as such may exhibit a sense of purpose and curiosity, as autotelic. This is different from being externally driven, in which case things such as comfort, money, power, or fame are the motivating force.

-[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotelic).

There is already noun translation, [autotélisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autot%C3%A9lisme), but is there an adjective for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following standard French convention for adjectives (i.e., ending in -que),
 we have:

- [**autotélique**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/autot%C3%A9lique)